# Find base class iname in class definition using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using Javascript.

I have a file that can be like this:

```
/* Loaded modules -- end */

class Element extends One(Two(PageElement)) {
  static get pagePath () { return [ '/elelel'] }

  static get styles () {
```

Or like this:

```
/* Loaded modules -- end */

class Element extends PageElement {
  static get pagePath () { return [ '/elelel'] }

  static get styles () {
```

I want to find `PageElement` in both cases using Javascript regexp.

I am up to here:

```
contents.match(/^[ \t]*class[ \t]+\w+[ \t]+extends[ \t]+(.*)$/m)
```

The first match in brackets is `One(Two(PageElement)) {`. I am having real trouble getting to match `PageElement` -- especially since that `One(Two(` (and the trailing closing brackets) might not be there.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse javascript with regex anyways?

Comment: A code generator. https://github.com/mobily-enterprises/js-kit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
/^\s*class\s+\w+\s+extends\s+(:?\w+\s*\(\s*)*(\w+)[\s)]*/m
```

The pattern `\w+\s*\(` matches a token followed by `(` (with optional whitespace around the `(`. This group followed by `*` allows any number of these (uncluding 0, so they're optional).

And `[\s)]*` allows any number of `)` after the superclass name (again, with optional spaces).

```js
function get_superclass(content) {

  let match = content.match(/^\s*class\s+\w+\s+extends\s+(?:\w+\s*\(\s*)*(\w+)[\s)]*/m);
  if (match) {
    return match[1];
  }
}

console.log(get_superclass(`/* Loaded modules -- end */

class Element extends PageElement {
  static get pagePath () { return [ '/elelel'] }

  static get styles () {`));

console.log(get_superclass(`/* Loaded modules -- end */

class Element extends One(Two(PageElement)) {
  static get pagePath () { return [ '/elelel'] }

  static get styles () {`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regex.

```
^[ \t]*class[ \t]+\w+[ \t]+extends[ \t]+(?:\w+\()*(\w+)[)\s]*{$
```

The Non capturing group `(?:\w+\()*` captures any set of characters followed by a open parenthesis and removes that from the actual data that we need to capture and similarly `[)\s]*` will match any closing brackets if they are available, hence leaving us with the exact class name that we are looking for.